# Should I set a boolean field as volatile?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

Is the following code thread-safe? Do I really need to set `dataReady` to be `volatile`, though there is only one write and multiple reads from one thread (with while loop as shown below)?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    /* a flag indicates if the data is fully retrieved from the database */
    private volatile boolean dataReady = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                // retrieve data from the database
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                dataReady = true;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public boolean isDataReady()
    {
        return dataReady;
    }
}
```

On other thread (not the main thread):

```
while(!getApplication().isDataReady()); // wait until the data is ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking the boolean as `volatile` guarantees visibility, in other words it guarantees that all threads will see its current value. Since you are making writes and reads in different threads, you have to mark the boolean as `volatile`.

If you don't mark it as `volatile`, it is very possible (but not systematic) that your main thread will set `dataReady` to true and the other thread will see the flag as false and continue looping. In a worse case scenario, it could even become an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
though there is only one write and multiple reads from one thread
```

When its the **single thread**, as mentioned by you is writing once and reading multiple times, then i dont think volatile is needed, as volatile reflects the changes done on the data by one thread on to the another,

But suppose you have **multiple threads** reading and writing the database, its better to make the **writing method/statement as synchronized**, and **use volatile on the data, which is retrieved from the database, so multiple access from threads can be given to read the data.**

Comment: It looks like his reads are in the same thread while the write is on a separate thread, since it's inside the AsyncTask?

Comment: Well then he can use synchronized on the write method, and using volatile on the data to be read, will provide good visibility to other threads. if mulitple threads are reading it...

Answer (score 0):

The code is not necessarily thread-safe. While I understand that the system may be engineered to ensure that only one thread ever creates an instance of MyApplication and then calls onCreate, that does not mean that code snippet you provided is itself thread-safe. Therefore, dataReady should be marked as volatile.

As you know, volatile means that there will be exactly one copy of the variable in main memory, as opposed to copies being cached by thread. I think this is most appropriate in this case.